# How to create shortcut within app in Android?

Tags: android, shortcut

I've added shortcuts options for my Android app, but I found out other apps can create shortcut within their apps (in their apps, press menu button, choose create shortcuts, then their shortcuts appear in the launcher), when my only tutorial from Android developer is only for creating shortcuts from launcher (long press in launcher home screen, choose Shortcuts, then choose your app).

Can anyone show me the way to create a shortcuts within app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside question is working solution, take a look. If you have any question add it in a comment.
[How to add app's shortcut to the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988511/how-to-add-apps-shortcut-to-the-home-screen)

Comment: Thanks. I gave up on this a long time ago, but it's still nice to have a proper answer.