# Display a YouTube like app menu when the user has long clicked on the app logo

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am working on an Android app and want to display a menu with some data about the app on a similar menu when you do a long click on the app logo in the main menu of the phone, like the one the YouTube app has, or other Android apps when pressed down.

I am working on Android Studio, and I've searched different sites for info on how to get to the menu, by default the android apps show a menu when long clicked, in which you can choose whether you want to delete the app or something else. I want to know how to access that menu.

At least I want to know the name of the menu so I can do more research, but if anyone knows how to interact with it, it would be great.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you mean [app shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog explains it nicely

```
https://medium.com/@andreworobator/implementing-android-app-shortcuts-74feb524959b
```

Also FYI, With Q Android is doing some changes in shortcuts api. Do check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

they're called Android App Shortcuts, this could help you answer your question [How to create shortcut within app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328390/how-to-create-shortcut-within-app-in-android)

Good luck! :)