# How to add shortcut to Home screen in android programmatically

Tags: android, homescreen

This issue has arisen when I was developing an android application. I thought of sharing the knowledge I gathered during my development.

Comment: to the mods that marked as duplicate: pls note that the answers on your duplicate do not fully address the question. Hence the OP decided to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), as advised. You will see that his self answer contains very different info to the accepted answer on the duplicate. Pls consider for reopening.

Comment: This seems like an easy way to gain reputation as he's almost reproducing an older article without even giving credits:http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcu t-example/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Android provide us an intent class `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` which can be used to add shortcuts to home screen. In following code snippet we create a shortcut of activity MainActivity with the name HelloWorldShortcut.

First we need to add permission `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` to android manifest xml.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

The `addShortcut()` method creates a new shortcut on Home screen.

```
private void addShortcut() {
    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity 
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Note how we create shortcutIntent object which holds our target activity. This intent object is added into another intent as `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT`.

Finally we broadcast the new intent. This adds a shortcut with name mentioned as
`EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME` and icon defined by `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE`.

Also put this code to avoid multiple shortcuts :

```
  if(!getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, false)){
          addShortcut();
          getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, true);
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the well investigated answer on undocumented functionality

Comment: Don´t worked for me

Comment: I think that now the play store automatically does that for the user. (Can be changed in the settings) so this would only make 2 icons on the desktop.

Comment: Add this `addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false)`
To stop being creating multiple shortcuts

Comment: Play store does it automaticlly

Comment: Where is the class Utils ?

Comment: @Chanaka Where should this code be added ? The short cut should appear on the home screen before the app is opened.

Comment: I think you need a `.commit()` at the end

Comment: can not resolve symbol "Utils"
I am getting this error.

Comment: It works for me.  Make sure activity exported, otherwise the launcher has no permission to start the activity.

Comment: This doesn't work in all devices.

Comment: What is utils ? I am getting "cannot resolve symbol utils"

Comment: this issue is not work on android 8.0 or oreo and newer

Comment: i'm looking for oreo and above

Comment: Please update the answer

Comment: In android oreo and above, try the pinned shortcuts - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/

Comment: note: this only seems to work pre API 26