# Android - Adding shortcut to homescreen and specifying which screen and position

Tags: android

Im attempting to develop an AllApps drawer like Aviate, but as a separate Activity (that way I can launch it from Nova Launcher through a gesture).

I've seen answers on how to add a shortcut to the homescreen. i.e.:

> [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen)
>
> [How to add shortcut to Home screen in android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programatically)

Is it possible to specify the which homescreen page and location? I'm guessing not since google playstore does not seem to put it in the best place on a new app install, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

On the default launchers, there is no documented way to do this.