# how to add shortcut icon on home screen in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am unable to add shortcut icon on home screen . i want to do this only using manifest and not by adding any method on activity.

i tired this code in manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.fz.atifandroid">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_image"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <!--<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>-->
</application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen/20536046#20536046)

Comment: Already answered in [How to add shortcut to Home screen in android programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link, as this question is similar to [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen).

One more way is if you are downloading the app from play store then in play store settings you can tick the **add icon to homescreen** then it will create the app icon in homescreen.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

in `Java`,

```
private void ShortcutIcon(){

Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Test");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Don't forget to add permission to `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Happy coding !!!

Comment: should shortcut icon be same as launcher icon? if yes, my launcher icon is placed in mimp folder instead of drawable folder, should i get shortcut icon resource from mimp folder?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to add permission INSTALL_SHORTCUT to android manifest xml.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

The addShortcut() method create a new shortcut on Home screen.

```
private void addShortcut() {
    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity 
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Also put this code to avoid multiple shortcuts :

```
 if(!getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, false)){
          addShortcut();
          getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, true);
      }
```

It is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programatically)

Comment: I am getting "cannot resolve symbol utils" error, how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 Line in after public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
final static public String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS_NAME";
final static private String PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED = "PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED";
```

and call in after MainActivity onCreate

```
 private void ShortcutIcon(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean shortCutWasAlreadyAdded = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED, false);
        if (shortCutWasAlreadyAdded) return;
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED, true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```