# Android: Homescreen Shortcut with Serializable Extra

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create a homescreen shortcut to an inner activity of my app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873257/3449811) answer helped to get me started.

Here's the basic code:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
        StationMainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, stationData.getName());
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context.getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));

addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
context.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Unfortunately, while it does work to provide an extra of type String the code appears to fail if I try to provide a serializable extra to the shortcutIntent.

```
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("StationId", (String) stationData.getId());
```

does work. But

```
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("StationData", stationData);
```

where stationData is a serializable Object does not. So right now I provide all fields of the object as string and recreate the object when the activity is called. This does work but it's cumbersome and dirty code.

Any idea why providing a serializable object does not work in this case? Thanks.

Update: Here's how I try to retrieve the Serializeable:

```
    stationData = (StationData) intent.getSerializableExtra("StationData");
```

StationData looks like this:

```
public class StationData implements Serializable {
    private String id; 
    private String name; 
    ...

    public StationData(String id, String name, ....) {
      this.id = id; 
      this.name = name; 
      ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your stationData extending from serializable? also can you provide the code on how are you getting the extras ?

Comment: Yes it is. Serialization works well if it is not used for the shortcut intent.

Comment: Can you provide the code when you retrieve the serialisable?

Comment: do you have a error or warning in your ADB ?

Answer (score 0):

when you try to get data try to use:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getSerializable("StationData");
```