# How to create Shortcut (URL) on Custom Home Page in Android

Tags: android

I can crate URL shortcut on Home page. But I want to know how we can create URL short cut on custom home page.

When I am trying to create in Custom home page it just creating in default home Page

Comment: Exactly you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programatically[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programatically)

Comment: This is just creating shortcut on home screen. Here I am talking about Custom Home Screem