# Installed unsigned APK is missing launcher icon

Tags: android

I've gone through the following steps in Android Studio to build an unsigned APK:

`Build > Build APK(s)`

Once the APK is built, I press the `Locate` hyperlink in the popup in the bottom right hand of my screen to locate the APK in my Finder.

I put this APK on dropbox and open up the public link to it on the phone I want to test with. I download and install the APK on phone, and everything works fine. The app launches fine.

The only problem is that it doesn't seem to have a launcher icon associated with it.

Here's what's in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectCoin"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Try this solution [Image ShortCut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Image Asset Studio** in following manner:

[image]

Then create a legacy launcher icon.

[image]

For more reference read [android developer Doc.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed to admit that I found the launcher icon under the expandable 6-dot icon among all the other apps installed on this particular phone. I had only been looking on the home screen.

Answer (score -1):

You should import your desired launcher icon 
by pressing new -> image asset in your android studio

hope this helps