# Duplicate Shortcut icon on Android

Tags: java, android

I followed [How can I add my application's shortcut to the homescreen upon app installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327173/how-can-i-add-my-applications-shortcut-to-the-homescreen-upon-app-installation) to have shortcut icon of my app on screen. It is working fine. But the issue is when I click on the shortcut icon to launch, it creates one more shortcut icon.

How to avoid that? In case I delete one icon, the app creates it again on opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a flag in Shared Preferences to keep track of whether I created a shortcut already or not.  From what I could find, there's no way to check if the shortcut already exists on the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with sharedpreference and saved its value first time and checking on next call before calling method to create shortcut. Working fine now.

Comment: It's the most reliable way I've found to date.