# How to add shortcut of an app to the homescreen in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an app I installed in android emulator. I want to know how I can add a shortcut to the app on the homescreen of my android emulator. For easy access mostly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327173/how-can-i-add-my-applications-shortcut-to-the-homescreen-upon-app-installation)

Comment: That links talks about adding a shortcut programmatically. I'm talking about manually, the way it is done in a real phone for example.

Comment: So you want to emulate user touches ?

Comment: But now for android emulator, not a physical device:)

Comment: Not really. Just to add a shortcut so I can quickly click on the app from the homescreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, as you do it on your physical device.
Just long press with left mouse button on the required app in the emulator, wait for a while, you will see the home screen, then release left mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works; but first you need to find a draggable version of the required app.

On the Android 12 emulator I am using I could find the app through search, but clicking the icon did not enable dragging and instead popped up a context menu.

The solution for me was to swipe up from the bottom of the "screen", this brought up the phone search screen.

From here I was able to drag the app to the home screen.