# Add Icon to homescreen only when run by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher, homescreen

Is there a way to add my application to homescreen through Android Studio on "Run" action? Maybe with adb?

I don't want to code it to add the icon on normal installation, only when it happens through Android Studio "Run" option - as I only need it for developing reasons.

---

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18327173/4577762) and consequently [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4854197/4577762) too, but I don't want it to happen every single time (as in from any installation of my app), but only when developing.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to see if app runned by android studio it self ?

- if its for debugging reasons cant you remove code after release ?

Possible answer:

- when you run by android studio RUN its **default** `Debug mode`
- when you publish your app you **must** set into `Release mode`

> How to Detect if I am in release or debug mode in android ?
>
> ```
> if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
>   // do something for a debug build
> }
> ```

based on [Detect if I am in release or debug mode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode-in-android)

**UPDATE**

if you think its hard to remove all dev only stuff from your code put them in

```
boolean devmode=true;
//----
if(devmode){
 //my dev only stuff
}
//----
```

So you can easily switch between dev and release

i use this way always maybe you can use too

Comment: It's not really about checking if run by AS, but maybe a configuration to auto-execute something at run command. Anyways, I'll be able to explore your suggestion more in depth later. Thanks for now ^^

Comment: Btw, removing code pre-release seems like a way to mess things up. Maybe not in this case, but I'm not sure I would personally advise it.

Comment: when i wanted to debug my app with Logs i made a function named LOG with string input there was a if in it to see if devmode bool is true or false then log the data if that was true