# Problems while trying to add a launcher shortcut to my app on Android Oreo and above

Tags: android, shortcut, launcher

I'm working on a simple application that has a button that creates a shortcut on the launcher to the main activity of my app.

I followed the following thread:
[How can I add my application's shortcut to the homescreen upon app installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327173/how-can-i-add-my-applications-shortcut-to-the-homescreen-upon-app-installation)

However, When I click on the button and execute the "createShortcut" function, no shortcut is being created. I'm testing my app on Galaxy S7 with android Oreo and on and Pixel 2 emulator running Android 8.1.

I would like if you could help me in solving this problem.
This is the The main activity:

```
package com.example.test_shortcut_application;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    public void createShortcut(View v){
        System.out.println("trying to add a shortcut to homescreen");
        Intent intentShortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        intentShortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
        Parcelable appicon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        intentShortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, appicon);
        intentShortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        intentShortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        sendBroadcast(intentShortcut);

    }



}
```

This is the main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="createShortcut"
        android:text="Add Shorcut"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="214dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="215dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the app manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_shortcut_application">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research, I found out that in Android Oreo and above the method of creating a shortcut is a little bit different.
I followed this tutorial from Android Authority:https://www.androidauthority.com/android-nougat-oreo-static-dynamic-pinned-shortcuts-845686/

Thankfully It worked!
I wish it will work for you as well