# Cordova: is there a way to tell Android system automatically add app icon to launcher?

Tags: android, cordova

I noticed that default behavior for most applications installed from Play Store is to automatically add an icon to the launcher in use (at least in Google Launcher).

I can't test on iOS but I guess that's the default behavior for any app, since there is no app drawer.

However when I deploy my Cordova app to device this doesn't happen. Is there a way to "tell" Android system to do it?

I simply have no clue if and how it's feasible.

Comment: it's a configuration on google play app, if the user set it, the icon will be added on the laucher, so if you install the app while developing the app this won't happen

Comment: done. I've added a bit more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option on Google Play app Settings, called "Add icon to Home screen" for new apps, it comes checked by default, so any app you install from google play will add the icon to Home screen, but apps installed while developing or downloaded from another sources won't

Comment: hey @icesarmobile, I'll accept the answer. However I believe apps can actually create the icon **programmatically** since native apps can actually create icons (some of them do it for spam, some other they just self-add themselves to launcher at runtime)

Comment: Yeah, it's possible, see this question (not the accepted answer) and all the links to other questions, but It doesn't work on all devices or android versions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988511/how-to-add-apps-shortcut-to-the-home-screen

Comment: thank you. very interesting. but it's just for native apps. isn't it?

Comment: You can create a cordova plugin that executes that code